# Signing API requests using AFNetworking 2.0

Tags: objective-c, ios7, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

So I'm using AFNetworking to consume an API.

This API requires all requests to be signed using an hmac. The hmac is calculated over a combination of headers, url and body. The hmac is then added as a custom header to the request.

Calculating the hmac and adding it to the headers isn't a problem. However, it seems that some headers get added "at the last minute" before processing the request.

My API Client is a subclass of `AFHTTPSessionManager`, and I've been looking for the best place to do the signing, and I'm currently doing it by overloading:

```
- (NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTaskWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
                          completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error))completionHandler
```

When I simulate the requests on a test API server to see what headers I'm receiving, there's always 2 additional headers that weren't present when I signed the request: `Accept-Encoding` and `Connection`, sometimes I also get the `Cookie` header.

The only headers that I add myself, beside the hmac signature, are `Accept` and `Content-Type` and a custom header specific to the APIi indicating my customer key.

So my question is, what's the best way/place to do this signing?

Answer (score 1):

AFNetworking isn't adding these headers, NSURLSession is (and NSURLConnection would if you switched to AFHTTPRequestOperationManager).

Technically, the "correct" method to override is `requestWithMethod: URLString: parameters: error:` on your request serializer subclass, and not your `AFHTTPSessionManager`.   But that won't fix your problem, since AFNetworking is not the one adding these headers.  (Your current approach is also fine, just less flexible if you need different behavior for different URLs).

Your possible solutions are (ordered from best to worst, in my opinion):

1. **Change your API to not use the headers in the hmac**, or to not use this hmac at all (does this hmac give you anything that HTTPS and SSL Pinning doesn't?)
2. **Manually set these headers in your request serializer / session manager subclass** (I don't *think* NSURL[Session|Connection] will override them).  There are a number of downsides; for example you'll have to manage cookie storage yourself using NSHTTPCookieStorage.  You'll also have to hope you get all of them, since Apple's documentation doesn't say which headers they add in which cases.
3. **Completely remove AFNetworking and NSURL[Session|Connection]** entirely, and replace it with something based on the lower-level CFNetwork framework (the [long-abandoned ASIHTTPRequest library](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) may be your best bet.)

---

**EDIT**:  One other idea - you could try calling `setTaskWillPerformHTTPRedirectionBlock:` on your `AFHTTPSessionManager`.  The HTTP headers might be added at that point, so you could recalculate the hmac there.  (I haven't tested this; please let me know how this works out.)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, unfortunately option 1 isn't an option, I have to use this API, and that's a requirement to use it out of their sandbox environment. 

I will definitely give a shot at option 2 and get back to you on that. Regarding option 3, if the project has been abandoned I'd rather avoid it for now.